# Code to simulate Collatz Conjecture is showing 1 as an even number

Tags: python, modulo, collatz

My code is the following

```
output_even = "Even: "
output_odd = "Odd: "

if varnum % 2 == 0:
 varnum /= 2
 print(output_even, varnum)
 time.sleep(0.1)
elif varnum % 2 != 0:
 varnum *= 3
 varnum += 1
 print(output_odd, varnum)
 time.sleep(0.1)
```

Output (integer 5):

Odd:  16

Even:  8.0

Even:  4.0

Even:  2.0

Even:  1.0

Conjecture not solved

I know that one should not be an even number. But for some reason, it is listed as an even number as shown by the output with the original number being 5.

Edit: Full loop with code for extra clarification hopefully

```
        while varnum != 1:
            if varnum % 2 == 0:
                print(output_even, varnum)
                varnum /= 2
                time.sleep(0.1)
            elif varnum % 2 != 0:
                print(output_odd, varnum)
                varnum *= 3
                varnum += 1
                time.sleep(0.1)
        if varnum == 1:
            print("Conjecture not solved")
        else:
            print("Conjecture solved")
```

Comment: I think your code is missing the enclosing looping syntax that somehow repeatedly runs this code. Cloud you include that, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 is even, though.

You're dividing `varnum` by 2 and then printing the result of that division.

Try swapping the arithmetic and printing operations.

Comment: I will try this, but I just want to learn a little as well

so, by doing the arithmetic and then printing it I am printing "odd" or "even" on the previous integer, not the one following the output_even or output_odd in the print statement?

Comment: It's similar in the odd case, where you output that 16 is odd (because 5 is odd).

Comment: Yeah that's basically what's happening: you decide `varnum` is odd because `varnum` had the value 5.  Then you triple it and add 1 (yielding 16) so you print that 16 is odd.

Comment: I see that makes more sense. Thank you so much :)
My code is now working!